# Suggestion: add "Search All Sites" feature to the SE mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, global-search

This is a suggestion. The Stack Exchange website has a "Search All Sites" text field in the upper right corner, but the mobile app does not have an equivalent feature.

Instead we must search each Stack Exchange site individually and doing this on a smartphone is difficult. So adding such a global search feature would make Q&A browsing and lookup for mobile users much easier...

Comment: That's not a search-all box in the top right, not even on the full site. It only ever searches the site you're on right now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, wow, I thought "search all sites" meant just that. When I open an Incognito window I'm not logged in to SE and I don't have any visible web history. Then when I go to the main SE page and search for "quantum" I get a bunch of results pointing to  physics.stackexchange.com. And when I go to physics.stackexchange.com I get the same results.

Comment: Oh, you mean stackexchange.com. Yeah, that one is all sites - I thought you meant the individual sites.

Answer (score 2):

You have to navigate to a site before you can search. You can't search from the main page.

Type your search request in the top bar like this one:

> [image]

<sub>(screenshot taken from a related post)</sub>

Comment: I may not know which site to look in and a mobile app is a difficult environment in which to perform this kind of iterative task. On the other hand, the Stack Exchange website has a "Search All Sites" text field in the upper right corner. So if I use it to search for "lxml", it finds all the SE sites that have QAs about lxml. I'm suggesting a parallelism between the mobile and website interfaces.

Comment: Then your question should clearly state that. Not sure if it is feasible from the app, but you can always ask of course.

Comment: Thanks. I got here through the "Feedback always welcome" button at the bottom of the SE main page. So it's not a question; it's a suggestion.