# How do you search all sites from the search bar or using responsive view?

Tags: support, search, responsive-design, global-search

I have a two-part question

At the top of every site, there is a search bar.

1. Is this search bar only relevant to the specific site? I.e. meta, photo, etc.
2. Can I look up all sites from the search bar at the top of the site. Is there a syntax or string combination I can type to do this?

Basically, I want to run strings and searches I would do on a main site:

I.e., I type backyard and it gives me all sites with a backyard question and I can go to whatever site it shows and figure if I want to join that community or not.

Currently, the only way to search all sites is to go to stackexchange.com but when you are there the view is really only for desktop. For phones with responsive view, you have to zoom in and out to accomplish this.

Related questions

["Search all sites" returns no results regardless of search term](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335226/1059647)

["search all sites" on StackExchange.com not returning results from site-specific search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134499/1059647)

["Search all Sites" UI is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321814/1059647)

[Suggestion: add "Search All Sites" feature to the SE mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289586/1059647)

Comment: Google is pretty good at searching all sites at once

Comment: ^ See: [Search all Stack Exchange Sites from Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298381/348196)

Comment: @KevinB yes but I’m looking for specific stuff that google wouldn’t have

Comment: @41686d6564 that’s a work around. Can my question be a feature request?

Comment: Searching on stackexchange.com from mobile is not really that bad. You only have to zoom for the search bar/field. Once you've entered your query, the results look pretty decent. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duUj0.png) - Edit: Okay maybe not the tags and timestamps.

Comment: @JcbJoe Yeah, sure. That's why I retracted my close vote and restored the [feature-request] tag once I realized you wanted this on mobile. I don't think this has a good chance of getting implemented though. That's why you should probably consider workarounds.

Comment: Related: [stackexchange.com homepage really needs a responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335961/348196)

Comment: @41686d6564 Can you write all that in an answer

Comment: [Google Search has become pretty bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48AOOynnmqU&t=48s) at finding anything. It is no longer 2003. For instance, it refuses to return the ***canonical*** questions on Stack Overflow from 2008 and 2009 (the typical result is a low-scored duplicate from 2015 with one or two low-quality answers). Allegedly, people are [fleeing to Reddit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48AOOynnmqU&t=5m10s).

Comment: Thanks for that info @This_is_NOT_a_forum